# XAUTHORITY environment variable empty in ssh session

Tags: ssh, x11, openssh

When I enter an SSH connection to a Linux host, the XAUTHORITY environment variable is unset. If I run `sudo -b`, the connection is dropped, unless I add a `nohup` command immediately after, in which case the operation fails, reporting `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.`

As a workaround, I can manually set the value to `$HOME/.Xauthority`.

This variable is typically set automatically. What should I do to ensure that the variable is set in the preferred way (by the right process at the right time)?

Answer (score 0):

If the Xauthority file is located at `$HOME/.Xauthority`, then you are not supposed to need the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, since `$HOME/.Xauthority` is the default path: the X11 libraries should be checking it automatically.

If you then use `sudo` to switch to root, then it becomes more difficult to maintain the X11 session access through `sudo`, as it's no longer just a matter of preserving the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables and letting the root user read the Xauthority from wherever it is: a suitable XAUTHORITY value will need to be set at some point to identify the actual location of the Xauthority file. It's not really important how it gets set, as long as it gets set before the process that will need it is started.

If `sudo` is already configured to preserve the `XAUTHORITY` variable, then you could work around this by explicitly setting `XAUTHORITY` in your login script (as your original user account before `sudo`) if `DISPLAY` is set, with something like this:

```
if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ] && [ "$XAUTHORITY" = "" ]; then
    export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
fi
```

Alternatively, if `sudo` does not preserve `XAUTHORITY` and/or you do not wish to configure `sudo` to preserve it, you could put the following snippet into the `/etc/bash.bashrc` or  `~/.bashrc` (or whatever script gets executed by the shell started by the `sudo` command).

```
if [ "$SUDO_USER" != "" ] && [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]; then
    export XAUTHORITY=$(getent passwd "${SUDO_USER}" | cut -d : -f 6)/.Xauthority
fi
```

Comment: There are two separate issues, apparently, setting the value on login versus carrying it into the environment created by `sudo`. It seems both are necessary, but you made a passing comment about `sudo` being "configured to preserve" `XAUTHORITY`. Would you please clarify? In my tests it is good enough for a value to be set in the environment inherited by  `sudo`, but the man page says otherwise, that the entire environment comes from a root login, except for any variables preserved by command line switch.

Comment: In modern distributions, `sudo` typically has the `env_reset` setting in effect by default (see `sudo -l`). When using `sudo` without the `-i` option, it is possible to configure `sudo` to preserve (carry) some environment variables, by adding e.g. `Defaults env_keep+=XAUTHORITY` to `/etc/sudoers` or to any drop-in files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Some distributions preserve some variables by default, others don't. Depending on `sudo` configuration, you may or may not also be able to specify it as a command-line option: `sudo --preserve-env=XAUTHORITY ...`.